# If there is a misprint on an instrument plate, is a pilot required to comply with it?

Tags: faa-regulations, approach, iaps, instrument-procedures

This is a snippet from the [KESC RNAV 36](http://goo.gl/1jqQ56) approach.  It's a real procedure, I didn't photoshop it except to add highlighting.

Let's say I was in the position that the blue aircraft is in (roughly 10 miles from WOKOL bearing approximately 320), and I had been cleared to WOKOL for the RNAV 36. I am assuming ATC did not explicitly tell me to do a procedure turn.

What am I supposed to do when I get to WOKOL?  The plate says NoPT, which is obviously a mistake.  Do I still fly the course reversal?  Do I whip into a 150 degree left turn over WOKOL as illustrated?

Here are some relevant passages from the AIM:

AIM 5-4-9:

> The procedure turn or hold-in-lieu-of-PT is a required maneuver when it is depicted on the approach chart, unless cleared by ATC for a straight-in approach. Additionally, the procedure turn or **hold-in-lieu-of-PT is not permitted when the symbol “No PT” is depicted** on the initial segment being used, when a RADAR VECTOR to the final approach course is provided, or when conducting a timed approach from a holding fix.

AIM 5-4-5 (D. 2. b.)

> The published procedure will be annotated to indicate when the course
>   reversal is not necessary when flying within a particular TAA area;
>   e.g., “NoPT.” Otherwise, the pilot is expected to execute the course
>   reversal under the provisions of 14 CFR Section 91.175. The pilot
>   **may elect** to use the course reversal pattern when it is not required by the procedure, but must inform air traffic control and
>   receive clearance to do so.

**If an instrument plate contains errors, am I still required to comply with them?**

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this plate. You simply enter the hold via a teardrop entry, which is not a PT. So after passing WOKOL you fly for 1 minute and then make a right turn to intercept the WOKOL 184 radial (004 inbound).

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert - NoPT also applies to hold-in-lieu-of-procedure-turn.  Reference AIM 5-4-9.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Are you *required* to fly the hold or do you have the option to fly the hold with ATC permission?  Reference AIM 5-4-5 (D.2.b.)

Comment: If I interpret this plate correctly, NoPT only applies north of WOKOL. But I could be wrong. I'm still in training for my IR.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert - You're interpreting the plate correctly.  The point is that the plate is wrong. NoPT is supposed to be on the south side of WOKOL, the quadrant *away* from the airport, but it's not.  The question is, do you still obey the chart when the chart is misprinted?

Comment: Now I may very well say something very stupid, but I still don't see anything wrong here. A PT is a maneuver to perform a course reversal. It doesn't necessarily say it should be a course reversal to fly inbound. The way I see it here: if you come from the south and you overshoot WOKOL you're not allowed to use a PT to reverse course if you need to join the hold (because of the "NoPT"). South of WOKOL it's perfectly fine. If that sounds stupid, it probably is. I'm a IR newbie :-)

Comment: The other obvious mistake on the plate is in the text: *"Rwy 36 Straight-in and Circling and Circling...."*  (how many times are you supposed to circle?)

Comment: @abelenky No, that's correct: the second "circling" applies to Rwy 18.

Comment: @Pondlife:  Rules of Grammar (not avaiation) mandate that commas separate subordinate phrases.  Without the comma, the text has too many "circlings".  It **should** read: *"Rwy 36 Straight-in and Circling, and Circling to Rwy 18, NA at night."*

Comment: For those that think that the chart is right, see my answer below.  The Jeppesen chart has it the other way.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The first thing that you should do is check the NOTAM's for the airport (which of course, you should do before you leave on your flight).  Very often, these types of errors have been discovered by someone else and the FAA will have issued a NOTAM to let everyone know.  In this case there is no NOTAM, so we would have had no reason to suspect an issue before we took off.

The main point has already been made.  If you are airborne and there is any reason to suspect that something is wrong, ask ATC for clarification and move on.

If I encountered this situation and couldn't ask for clarification (ie. lost communication) then I would simply select a different approach and fly it.

For the record, the Jeppesen chart has it coded correctly:

[image]

Now, aside from the operational considerations, it is very important to notify the FAA when you find discrepancies like this so that they can be fixed.  Here is a quote from the [Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/Chart_Users_Guide_12thEd.pdf):

> **REPORTING CHART DISCREPANCIES**
>
> Your experience as a pilot is valuable
>   and your feedback is  important. We make every effort to display
>   accurate information  on all FAA charts and publications, so we
>   appreciate your input.  Please notify us concerning any requests for
>   changes, or potential  discrepancies you see while using our charts
>   and related products.
>
> **FAA, AeroNav Products**
>   **SSMC4 Sta. 4503**
>   **1305 East-West Highway**
>   **Silver Spring, MD 20910-3281**
>
> **Telephone Toll-Free 1-800-626-3677**
>   **E-mail: 9-AMC-Aerochart@faa.gov**
>
> Mark the chart you are using with the suggested
>   changes and  include an explanation of the discrepancy. Mail this
>   corrected  chart to the address above and we will send you a
>   replacement  right away. Suggestions concerning this guide are also
>   welcome.

For the record, I have already emailed the plate with the suggested changes to the email address above (on 24 DEC 2013), and hopefully a NOTAM will be issued soon and an amended approach procedure will follow sometime after.

---

## Update (09 JAN 2014)

I received the following response from the FAA:

> Dear Louis:
>
> Thank you for reporting the problem
>
> ...
>
> Control Number 18335 has been assigned to this issue for tracking
>   purposes.  This concern has been closed with the following Response:
>
> **Thank You for your inquiry. A P-NOTAM is being assigned to correct the discrepancy.**
>
> Regards,

Note that the NOTAM hasn't been issued as of yet.

## Update 2 (17 JAN 2014)

New NOTAM issued to address the error on the instrument approach procedure:

```
!FDC 4/3036 ESC IAP DELTA COUNTY, ESCANABA, MI.
   RNAV (GPS) RWY 36, ORIG...
     CHANGE TAA TO READ FROM 274/30 CW 094/30 (NOPT) TO WOKOL
     (IF/IAF) AND FROM 094/30 CW 274/30 TO WOKOL (IF/IAF).
   THIS IS RNAV (GPS) RWY 36, ORIG-A.
   1401171859-PERM
```

## Update 3 (06 MAR 2014):

New, corrected chart issued and the NOTAM was cancelled the next day.

Comment: Nice answer.  The only problem is that if I notify the FAA and they fix it, how am I going to confuse CFI-I candidates during the oral portion of the check?

Comment: Upvoted for both the excellent answer and the fact you reported it to the FAA!

Answer (score 11):

The literal answer to your question about complying with the plate is also in AIM 5-4-9, right after the piece you quoted (my bold):

> NOTE- The pilot may elect to use the procedure turn or
>   hold-in-lieu-of-PT when it is not required by the procedure, but must
>   first receive an amended clearance from ATC. **If the pilot is uncertain
>   whether the ATC clearance intends for a procedure turn to be conducted
>   or to allow for a straight-in approach, the pilot must immediately
>   request clarification from ATC** (14 CFR Section 91.123).

In other words, any time you aren't sure or you suspect something is odd then you should just ask ATC.

On the other hand, if your question is about this specific procedure and whether the NoPT notation is (or even can be) correct or not, you might want to phrase your question in that way.

Answer (score 6):

Other RNAV approaches have the NoPT labeled on the the side away from the runway. This one is probably a misprint. If you believe an approach is incorrect, you should ask ATC just to make sure. If you feel the need to differ from an approach as published, whether because of a misprint, weather, traffic, a whim, or an emergency, you should ask or inform ATC.